# How to "view on Google maps" with react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

Very simply, how to display a link in an embedded GoogleMap to open the map on Google maps.

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={11}
    defaultCenter={{
        lat: parseFloat(props.mapCenter.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(props.mapCenter.lng)
    }}
    center={{
        lat: parseFloat(props.mapCenter.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(props.mapCenter.lng)
    }}
    defaultOptions={{
        controlSize: 20,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,

        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
        styles: mapStyles
    }}
>
```

Is there an option to display a link to "view on Google maps" as there is when in street view mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [react-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps) is a library created to use [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview). If you would like to use [Maps Embed API in streetview mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map#streetview_mode), you can do it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MAPS!</h1>
      <p>Please see map below</p>
      <iframe
        width="600"
        height="450"
        style={{ border: 0 }}
        loading="lazy"
        allowfullscreen
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=YOUR_API_KEY&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is a [sample working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/embed-streetview-dc71sq?file=src/index.js).Please use your own API key to make the code work.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use the GoogleMap object from react-google-maps.  What I want to know is how to create a link to open the embedded map in a new tab.  There is an option to show a full screen map -- is there an option to 'view in Google maps.'

Comment: The GoogleMap object will show Maps JavaScript Map object while Maps Embed API should be used inside an <iframe/>. If you would like to see the coordinates in maps.google.com in a new tab, you can use something like `"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" +e.latLng.lat() +","+e.latLng.lng()`
Here you will pass the latLng of the place and put it in a maps.google.com URL.

Comment: To see the streetview link in google maps you can use this  `"https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&&heading=-45&pitch=38&fov=80&viewpoint=" +this.state.center.lat +","+this.state.center.lng`. Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/maps-url-creation-on-click-llrk82?file=Map.js).

Comment: I don't want to have to be in street view to have the option to view in Google Maps.  I want to be able to display the link from somewhere within the map, like the expand map icon option.